# How to use multiple SMTP in django_mail_admin (Gmail & Outlook)

Tags: django, email, admin

We are using django_mail_admin in our project to send and receive emails.
Our requirement is to send email on both accounts Gmail and Outlook.
1- Gmail Account will send E-mail to Gmail account using Gmail SMTP
2- Outlook Account will send E-mail to Outlook account using outlook SMTP.
NOTE: Switch SMTP is a function to change SMTP according to Gmail and Outlook.
Use of single Gmail account :-
Gmail is sending Email to Gmail account, Sender and Receiver both from Gmail, working fine.
Use of single Outlook account :-
Outlook is sending Email to Outlook account, Sender and Receiver both from Outlook, working fine.
Use of Gmail and outlook together
When we use Gmail and outlook together and we Switch SMTP Gmail to Outlook, then we are facing issue (Sender not changing, Gmail Receive email from Gmail but Outlook Receive email from Gmail)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use multiple SMTP by adding below code in settings.py

    DJANGO_MAIL_ADMIN = {
        'BACKENDS': {
            'default': 'django_mail_admin.backends.CustomEmailBackend',
            'smtp': 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend',
        }
    }

    EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = "any"
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "any"
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


use 'default' for outlook and 'smtp' for gmail then it work for both 

# If you omit `backend_alias` argument, `default` will be used
mail.send(
    'from@example.com',
    ['recipient@example.com'],
    subject='Hello',
)

# If you want to send using `smtp` backend
mail.send(
    'from@example.com',
    ['recipient@example.com'],
    subject='Hello',
    backend='smtp',
)
```